# Отображение картинок в ListView в зависимости от типа объекта

Tags: android, listview

Итак. Предположим есть у нас некий массив, в котором хранятся объекты разных типов. Нужно в зависимости от типа объекта выводить определённую картинку. У меня есть идея, что нужно переписать адаптер, но может быть есть какие-то другие решения этого вопроса?

Comment: кроме собственного адаптера нет решений этого вопроса. Разработчики не подумали, что вам такое может понадобиться и не включили такой адаптер в API, гады :)

Answer (score 0):

Как сказал оратор выше — однозначно нужно писать свой адаптер, готовых реализация для такой задачи нет и быть не может (разве что в самых дальних и темных местах GitHub'a).

Однако, подход с определением объекта (если Вы хотите это делать через `instanceof`) — не правильный. В Вашем случае лучше сделать так, чтобы все Ваши объекты реализовали определенный интерфейс и сами говорили, что требуется отобразить.